# Moose - Retain the original value of an attribute in a second attribute

Tags: perl, moose

I'm trying to create an object that will fetch a resource from the web, and needs to remember both where the resource was found eventually, as well as what the original URL was that we gave it.

I don't want to have to specify the URL twice, nor do I want to have loads of conditionals every time I want to use the URL to figure out whether I should use the "url" attribute or the "updated URL" attribute or some such, so I thought I'd create a second attribute with `default` property set to initialize from the original URL:

```perl
package foo;

use Moose;

has 'url' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str',
    required => 1,
);

has 'original_url' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Str',
    default => sub { shift->url },
);
```

If this would have worked (see below), then I would have been able to change the `url` at will, and just use the `url` attribute whenever I need to access the "current" URL; and then later on, if I need to see if the `url` was ever changed, I can just compare the `url` attribute against the `original_url` attribute, and go from there.

The problem with this, however, is that the order of initialization of these attributes seems to be not well defined; sometimes the `default` sub for the `original_url` attribute is called before the `url` property has a value, which means it will return `undef`, which obviously causes an error.

I thought of making `original_url` a `lazy` attribute, add a `predicate` and then add a `trigger` on `url` to update `original_url` to the old value if its predicate says it hasn't been set yet, but it turns out that triggers are called *after* the value has been changed, so I don't think I can do that.

Is there a method to accomplish what I'm trying to do that won't cause errors?

Comment: Sorry, too hot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use `BUILD` or `BUILDARGS`.

Just use `init_arg` to cause both attributes to be initialized from the same argument.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;
use warnings;

{
   package Foo;

   use Moose;

   has url => (
      is       => 'rw',
      isa      => 'Str',
      required => 1,
   );

   has original_url => (
      is       => 'ro',
      init_arg => 'url',
   );
}

my $o = Foo->new( url => 'a' );
say $o->url;                      # a
say $o->original_url;             # a
```

This approach makes it trivial and efficient to "backup" multiple attributes.

```perl
for my $name (qw( url ... )) {
   has "original_$name" => (
      is       => 'ro',
      init_arg => $name,
   );
}
```

Whichever technique you use, you probably want to avoid `isa` on the attribute for the original. There's no point in validating the input twice, and I suspect it would lead to confusing messages if you did.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know you could do that. Does make it more efficient, indeed.

Comment: `has` is just an ordinary function.

Comment: I know, but it must have a mapping somewhere to tell Moose that some init_arg must be stored in a property. I was (apparently incorrectly) assuming that if you add an init_arg, it deletes any mappings that may already exist for that name.

Answer (score 4):

What about setting the value in the BUILD?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{   package Foo;
    use Moose;

    has url => (
        is       => 'rw',
        isa      => 'Str',
        required => 1,
    );

    has original_url => (
        is       => 'ro',
        writer   => 'copy_url',
        isa      => 'Str',
        init_arg => undef,
    );

    sub BUILD {
        my ($self) = @_;
        $self->copy_url($self->url);
    }
}

my $o = 'Foo'->new(url => 'a');
$o->url('b');
$o->original_url eq 'a' or die;
```

You could do it in BUILDARGS, too, but I don't think it's the right place for such an action:

```perl
    has _original_url => (
        reader => 'original_url',
        isa    => 'Str',
    );

    around BUILDARGS => sub {
        my ($orig, $class, %args) = @_;
        $args{_original_url} = $args{url};
        $class->$orig(%args)
    }
```

Comment: @WouterVerhelst: See the update for another option (but not as good).

Comment: Yeah, I agree; the BUILD option seems better.

Comment: @choroba, See my answer for another option (but better) :)

Comment: @ikegami: Interesting idea indeed!